# boost_program_options_FOUND issue in RBuildTools when compiling in windows

Tags: r, boost, cmake, rcpp

I'm trying to compile C++ code for an R package and during the 'Rcmd.exe INSTALL' call this error about boost_program_options_FOUND happens. I've put 'set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)' in my CMakeLists.txt file with no luck. How to fix this?

```
make[1]: Leaving directory '/d/OneDrive/Documents/flashlighttext/src/build'
CMake Error at C:/RBuildTools/4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/cmake/Boost-1.81.0/BoostConfig.cmake:141 (find_package):
  Found package configuration file:

    C:/RBuildTools/4.3/x86_64-w64-mingw32.static.posix/lib/cmake/boost_program_options-1.81.0/boost_program_options-config.cmake

  but it set boost_program_options_FOUND to FALSE so package
  "boost_program_options" is considered to be NOT FOUND.  Reason given by
  package:

  No suitable build variant has been found.

  The following variants have been tried and rejected:

  * libboost_program_options-mt-x64.a (static, Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS=OFF)
```

Comment: The Boost `program_options` library needs linking. So you need to supply a library.  Moreover it is commonly used for standalone programs with a `main()` so it usually is not needed for work with `Rcpp` which extendds R.  But we cannot say more as you did not supply a [minimally complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)..

Comment: In any event, the error appears to come from the CMake invocation. R itself never uses CMake; some libraries might.  So I think this may be more of a question for `flashlighttext` than for Rcpp.

Comment: You were absolutely right, thank you! The solution was fork the KenLM project (instead of flashlighttext) and then set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON). No clue what it does, but it worked. And my apologies for not supplying a reprex, I was so lost that I couldn't even come up with it. And btw, big fan of yours here, Dirk. Keep up the good work and thank you for your time helping me.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted out!